# How to find duplicates in a table using Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I try to use an SQL query in Access but it doesn't work. Why?

```
SELECT * FROM table
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table;
```

I have a syntax error in FROM statement.

Comment: Does Access really support EXCEPT?

Comment: I am not sure Access supports EXCEPT keyword.

Comment: doesn't work means ?...

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The query doesn't make sense.  For instance, the number of columns should be the same in the two `select` statements and MS Access doesn't support `EXCEPT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use HAVING COUNT(name) > 1 clause

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE [name] IN 
(SELECT name, Count(name)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name)>1)
```

Answer (score 6):

MS Access does not support EXCEPT keyword. You can try using the LEFT JOIN like this:

```
select t1.* from table t1 left join table t2 on t1.name = t2.name
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to find the duplicates in your table then you can try this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You can also refer: [Create a Query in Microsoft Access to Find Duplicate Entries in a Table](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/create-a-query-in-microsoft-access-to-find-duplicate-entries-in-a-table/) and follow the steps to find the duplicates in your table.

> First open the MDB (Microsoft Database) containing the table you want
>   to check for duplicates.  Click on the Queries tab and New.
>
> [image]
>
> This will open the New Query dialog box.  Highlight Find Duplicates
>   Query Wizard then click OK.
>
> [image]
>
> Now highlight the table you want to check for duplicate data.  You can
>   also choose Queries or both Tables and Queries.  I have never seen a
>   use for searching Queries … but perhaps it would come in handy for
>   another’s situation.  Once you’ve highlighted the appropriate table
>   click Next.
>
> [image]
>
> Here we will choose the field or fields within the table we want to
>   check for duplicate data.  Try to avoid generalized fields.
>
> [image]
>
> Name the Query and hit Finish.  The Query will run right away and pop
>   up the results.  Also the Query is saved in the Queries section of
>   Access.
>
> [image]
>
> Depending upon the selected tables and fields your results will look
>   something similar to the shots below which show I have nothing
>   duplicated in the first shot and the results of duplicates in the
>   other.
>
> [image] [image]

Comment: This query shows more records than are in the table. I want only select records which names are not unique.

Comment: @maro:- Do you want to find duplicates in your table? If yes then I have updated my answer. If no, then please clarify!

Comment: Rahul: yes. I changed the title of the question.

Comment: @maro:- Have you checked the EDIT which I made? That will resolve your purpose!

Comment: The second query is almost that what I meant. It shows proper number of records, but I want to have the same attributes as in the original table. How to do that?

Comment: @maro: `but I want to have the same attributes as in the original table.` What do you mean by this? If you mean the same column names then you can write the column names in select as well as Group By clause

Comment: @maro:- You can also use the wizard by following the steps mentioned in here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/create-a-query-in-microsoft-access-to-find-duplicate-entries-in-a-table/\

Comment: This wizard was very helpful. I didn't know about it :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LEFT JOIN or EXISTS

LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.NAME FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 on t1.name=t2.name
WHERE t2.name is null
;
```

NOT EXITS

```
SELECT T1.NAME FROM table1 as t1 where not exists
(SELECT T2.NAME FROM table2 as t2 where t1.name=t2.name)
```

Comment: I have only one table. These queries show an empty table. So it's not the same what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Whether Access supports `except` or not is one issue.  The other is that you are not using it properly.  You have `select *` above the word `except` and `select name` below.  That is not valid sql.  If you tried that in SQL Server, your error message would be `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.`

Comment: So how can I select all records from a table where names are not unique?